Spring Session MongoDB - How to implement Session Registry
I want to implement this handler:
@Component
internal class CustomConcurrentSessionControlSuccessHandler(
    reactiveSessionRegistry: ReactiveSessionRegistry,
    maximumSessionsExceededHandler: ServerMaximumSessionsExceededHandler
) : ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomConcurrentSessionControlSuccessHandler::class.java)

    private val delegate: ConcurrentSessionControlServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler =
        ConcurrentSessionControlServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
            reactiveSessionRegistry,
            maximumSessionsExceededHandler
        )

    init {
        // configure the default session limit
        delegate.setSessionLimit(SessionLimit.of(1))
    }

    // override method
    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(
        webFilterExchange: WebFilterExchange,
        authentication: Authentication
    ): Mono<Void> {

        logger.info("Successfully authenticated: {}", authentication.name)
        return delegate.onAuthenticationSuccess(webFilterExchange, authentication)
    }
}

But I cannot implement a Mongo Session equivalent of this, since
public SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionRegistry(     
    org. springframework. session. ReactiveSessionRepository<S> sessionRepository,
    org. springframework. session. ReactiveFindByIndexNameSessionRepository<S> indexedSessionRepository )

The two repositories, MongoIndexedSessionRepository implements FindByIndexNameSessionRepository but is not reactive, and ReactiveMongoSessionRepository is reactive but does not implement FindByIndexNameSessionRepository?
Because I cannot create a reactiveSessionRegistry, I cannot implement a ConcurrentSessionControlServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler...
Any ideas?
